# How should we tag The Dark Crystal: Age of Resistance Tactics?

Tags: discussion, tags

We just got [our first question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371127/maximum-level-in-the-dark-crystal-age-of-resistance-tactics) for The Dark Crystal: Age of Resistance Tactics, and I'm at a loss for how to best tag it.

- the-dark-crystal-age-of-resistance-tactics is 42 characters.
- dark-crystal-age-of-resistance-tactics is 38 characters.

It's a side game for the TV show The Dark Crystal: Age of Resistance, which is itself a prequel to the original The Dark Crystal, so removing any of 'the-dark-crystal', 'age-of-resistance' or 'tactics' from the tag seems like it could cause problems for its findability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would something like dark-crystal-aor-tactics work? It keeps most of the main bits of the title.

Comment: I've gone ahead with [[tag:the-dark-crystal-aor-tactics]] and added a synonym of [[tag:dark-crystal-age-of-resistance-tac]] as well

Comment: Sounds good to me. Thanks to you both!